# When madhiyy touches to clothes can i have to do ghusal

Tags: masturbation

Asslamoalaikuum to all of my brothers and sisters .. Well my question is only that i know when madhiyy comes out then you don’t need to do ghusal but if madhiyy touches to your cloth then we have to do ghusal or just wash our clothes at the point where madhiyy touches ? Plz answer simple that only u have to wash your cloth at the point where madhiyy touches or that you have to do ghusal plzz in simple english iam not good in English plz Answer It’s very necessary for me

Comment: Why should the same reason of impurity create two different rulings?

Comment: Sorry I didn’t get that plz in simple language iam not good in english when only madhiyy comes not maniyy and when that madhiyy touches to clothes then we have to just wash the cloth at the point where ever madhiyy touches or we have to change the clothes and do ghusal ? plz in Simple english

Answer (score -1):

Brother please do not tell me that you have not been making ghusl every time semen has come out?

You MUST make ghusl everytime maniy comes out! Everytime you ejaculate/come and there is white semen visible, you must do a fard ghusl. This is Maniy.

Wadiy is preseminal fluid or the watery substance that comes before Madiy. This requires wudu not ghusl.

There is one case in which Maniy does not necessitate ghusl but do not worry about that: just make sure you are making ghusl everytime semen comes out to be on the safe side.

You must wash the part of the clothing where semen has fallen until it is very clean. Rinse 3 times if needed minimum. As for dry semen, Aisha peace be upon her scraped dry semen/Madiy off the clothing of the Prophet.

In another Hadith, it mentioned washing as well.

'Amr b. Maimun said:

I asked Sulaiman b. Yasar whether the semen that gets on to the garment of a person should be washed or not. He replied: A'isha told me: The Messenger of Allah (ﷺ) washed the semen, and then went out for prayer in that very garment and I saw the mark of washing on it.
وَحَدَّثَنَا أَبُو بَكْرِ بْنُ أَبِي شَيْبَةَ، حَدَّثَنَا مُحَمَّدُ بْنُ بِشْرٍ، عَنْ عَمْرِو بْنِ مَيْمُونٍ، قَالَ سَأَلْتُ سُلَيْمَانَ بْنَ يَسَارٍ عَنِ الْمَنِيِّ، يُصِيبُ ثَوْبَ الرَّجُلِ أَيَغْسِلُهُ أَمْ يَغْسِلُ الثَّوْبَ فَقَالَ أَخْبَرَتْنِي عَائِشَةُ أَنَّ رَسُولَ اللَّهِ صلى الله عليه وسلم كَانَ يَغْسِلُ الْمَنِيَّ ثُمَّ يَخْرُجُ إِلَى الصَّلاَةِ فِي ذَلِكَ الثَّوْبِ وَأَنَا أَنْظُرُ إِلَى أَثَرِ الْغَسْلِ

Be safe brother, take these things very seriously and may Allah reward you,

Salaam.

Comment: The Hadith you quoted itself says مَنِي. Madhiy is different from maniy, and it is not semen